# C# Unit Testing Async Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, unit-testing, asynchronous

Just to set the question, when I have come to write a unit test I hit the following error:

> Error: The source IQueryable doesn't implement
>   IDbAsyncEnumerable

The problem happens when testing a method which calls ToListAsync(), the unit test is as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Method1CallsCount()
{
    //arrange
    MockContainer container = new MockContainer();

    IQueryable<Entity1DTO> querableentity1DTO = new List<Entity1DTO>().AsQueryable();

    container.DefaultQueryFactory.Setup(p => p.Load(It.IsAny<ContextEnums>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Entity1, Entity1DTO>>>(),
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Entity1, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(querableentity1DTO);  

    var manager = new Manager1(container.DefaultQueryFactory.Object);

    //act
    var result = await manager.Method1();

    //assert
    //container.repo1.Verify(x => x.repoMethod(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Entity1,bool>>>()), Times.Once);
}
```

And here is the method I am testing:

```
public async Task<List<Entity1DTO>> Method1()
{
    Expression<Func<Entity1, Entity1DTO>> select = (x => new Entity1DTO()
    {
             ...   
            });

    Expression<Func<Entity1, bool>> where = (x => x.Property == "Test");

    return await _defaultQueryFactory.Load(ContextEnums.Enum1, select, where).ToListAsync();

}
```

To help a bit, I've tried mocking up the method that loads the data in the query factory and the error appears because the DTO model doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable, now the method that is getting tested sends off a select statement and a where statement and an entity type which the query factory then uses to generate a query this is then executed with ToListAsync() when it returns from the load Method. The error message shows that the DTO model is the one that doesn't implement the IDbAsync not the DB entity itself.

I understand that there are a few other questions out there that are simular but my difference is that I use a DTO model and the method in question does not use the context itself as it is injected into the load method and not in the place in which ToListAsync() is called.

anyone any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to run this against ` List<Entity1DTO>()` ? In this case the message is pretty clear. You can't use EF-specific methods like `ToListAsync` with any queryable. `

Comment: the Load method generates a query the ToListAsync executes said query the only reason the DTO model is there is because we select out the results into a new model @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: this is all done in the load method, its used so that a generic load method can be used and the only thing that needs to be defined is the type, select and where statement @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two problems here, firstly you do need to use the solution in the other answer and change the return type to TestDbAsyncEnumerator and the other problem is to do with Moq, the setup needs to have the same parameters called, so in your case you have

```
return await _defaultQueryFactory.Load(ContextEnums.Enum1, select, where).ToListAsync();
```

and

```
container.DefaultQueryFactory.Setup(p => p.Load(It.IsAny<ContextEnums>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Entity1, Entity1DTO>>>(),
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Entity1, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(querableentity1DTO);
```

notice how you have two extra parameters on the end, try leaving them as null. That should sort out the problem, just to make sure try adding an item to the return list as well.

Comment: ah that works, it was a combination of both answers. Since you managed to solve the error completely then you can have the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Error happens because Entity Framework async extension methods does not work with any `IQueryable` - it should also implement `IDbAsyncEnumerable` interface. Consider this:

```
var query = new List<EntityDTO>().AsQueryable();
var result = query.ToListAsync().Result;
```

This will throw the same exception you observe in your code. `EnumerableQuery` returned by `AsQueryable` does not implement required interface, so we need to use some other implementation. We can find one in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx) article (or just create ourselves since it's not hard):

```
static class TestExtensions {
    public static IQueryable<T> AsAsyncQueryable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
        return new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<T>(source);
    }
}

internal class TestDbAsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>
{
    public TestDbAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        : base(enumerable)
    { }

    public TestDbAsyncEnumerable(Expression expression)
        : base(expression)
    { }

    public IDbAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator()
    {
        return new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
    }

    IDbAsyncEnumerator IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()
    {
        return GetAsyncEnumerator();
    }
}

internal class TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T> : IDbAsyncEnumerator<T> {
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _inner;

    public TestDbAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner) {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        _inner.Dispose();
    }

    public Task<bool> MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        return Task.FromResult(_inner.MoveNext());
    }

    public T Current => _inner.Current;

    object IDbAsyncEnumerator.Current => Current;
}
```

Now we can do:

```
IQueryable<Entity1DTO> querableentity1DTO = new List<Entity1DTO>().AsAsyncQueryable();
```

And EF async methods will execute correctly on it.

Comment: Since you mock your query factory to always return `querableentity1DTO` - if that `querableentity1DTO` is now TestDbAsyncEnumerable - it should not throw the same error, I've tested it with simple code from my answer.

Comment: in the test above I changed the line IQueryable<Entity1DTO> querableentity1DTO = new List<Entity1DTO>().AsQueryable(); to the async one and had the default query factory return  querableentity1DTO and that still doesn't appear to work

Comment: Maybe you should check with debugger that `_defaultQueryFactory.Load(ContextEnums.Enum1, select, where)` returns value of correct type (`TestDbAsyncEnumerable`).

Comment: after debugging in it is still returning the Entity1DTO Type does this mean the method is not being intercepted by the mocked object?

Comment: It cannot return Entity1DTO type, because it's not `IQueryable` so you cannot call `ToListAsync` on it. It can return something like `TestDbAsyncEnumerable<Entity1DTO>` or `EnumerableQuery<Entity1DTO>`

Comment: sorry i meant  IQueryable<Entity1DTO>

Comment: Still cannot be, because it should be some type _implementing_ `IQueryable<Entity1DTO>`. Variable is always of some type. What `_defaultQueryFactory.Load(ContextEnums.Enum1, select, where).GetType()` shows?

Comment: System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Entity1DTO]} is the underlying type, sorry i thought you meant the return type of the method

Comment: So that's what I'm talking about - for whatever reasons `TestDbAsyncEnumerable` which I provide in my answer is not used. `EnumerableQuery` is what is returned by `AsQueryable`, not by `AsAsyncQueryable`. Maybe you use `AsQueryable` in multiple places, maybe some other problem - hard to say with provided information.

Comment: what more would you need to help out? anything i can provide to help solve the problem?

Comment: Well as usual easiest way to solve problem is to post complete, minimal reproducable example which people can just copy paste and run to reproduce the problem